# Changing Xamarin Forms App Page from a View Model

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, viewmodel

Currently in my view model when a command is executed i am attempting to change the page of the app by using this:

```
Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ArticlePage());
```

However when the command is executed it goes right past this and the page hasn't been changed. Is the code wrong or is there more to this then one line?

Thanks,

Ryan

Comment: Have you debugged this app to determine if really does `goes right past this` ?

Comment: @Saruman When I step into the code using the debugger it accesses the .cs of the page im trying to push it to and even though it accesses the InitializeComponent() it doesn't change the page.

Comment: have you tried `await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PushAsync(new ArticlePage());`

Comment: yeah no luck @Saruman, unfortunately made no difference

Comment: Try this Application.Current.MainPage = new ArticlePage(); might works.

Comment: Thanks @SrustiThakkar it seemed to work, still cannot figure out why the regular method doesn't work thou

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at "Pushing Pages to the Navigation Stack" - 
 [Xamarin documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical#pushing-pages-to-the-navigation-stack)

in the documentation,the following is used to navigate.

> await Navigation.PushAsync (new Page2Xaml ());

When you use the entire path like you are, the reference is incorrect or some kind of exception is being raised.

You can also use try/catch to see if there is an exception being raised.